# CAPL: int to byte and binary arrays

Tags: arrays, capl

I'm trying to understand how binary arrays work. Here is a CAPL example that converts a decimal number into a binary array:

```
byte binaryArray[16];

binary ( int number ) 
{

   int index; 
   index = 0;

   for ( ; number != 0; ) 
   {
       binaryArray[index++] = number % 10;
       number = number / 10;
   }
}
```

If the input is 1234, the output is apparently 11010010

If I'm not mistaken, the for loop runs 4 times:

- 1234 mod 10 -> 4
- 123 mod 10 -> 3
- 12 mod 10 -> 2
- 1 mod 10 -> 1

If we weren't dealing with a binary array, it would look like this: { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }. But it is a binary array, and the "conversion" should happen here: `binaryArray[index++] = number % 10;` (number is a 16-bit signed integer, binaryArray is a 8-bit unsigned byte).

So how does one convert (by hand) an int to a byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it very hard to "guess" what your actual intent is and the given example is not really fitting to what I think you want to do. But I will give it a try.

As you have already explained by yourself, your example code always cuts the least significant digit in a base-10 system (i.e. the ones place) of the given integer "number" and then stores it sequentially into a byte array.

> If the input is 1234, the output is apparently 11010010

This statement is false. Currently, if the input for your given function is 1234, the "output" (i.e. binaryArray contents) is

```
binaryArray = { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Furthermore, the actual binary representation (assuming "MSB0 first/left" and big-endian) of your input number as byte array is

```
{ 0b00000100, 0b11010010 }
```

Because of your "apparently" (wrong) statement and your final question, I guess what you really want to achieve and what you're actually asking for is: *serialization of an integer into a byte array* - which first seems quite simple, but actually there are some pitfalls you can run into for multi-byte values - especially when you work together with others (e.g. endianness and bit-ordering).

Assuming you have a 16-bit integer, you could store the first 8-bits (byte) in binaryArray[0] and then shift your input integer by 8 bits to the right (since you already stored those). Now you can finally store the remaining 8 bits into binaryArray[1].

Given your example input of 1234 you will end up with the array

```
binaryArray = { 210, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

which is equivalent to its "binary" representation:

```
binaryArray = { 0b11010010, 0b00000100, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000 }
```

Notice that this time the byte-order (i.e. endianness) is reversed (little-endian) since we fill the array "bottom up" and the inputs "binary values" are read "right-to-left".

---

But since you have this 16-cells byte array you might instead want to convert the integer "number" into an array, *representing* its binary format, e.g. binaryArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }.

You could achieve this easily by substituting the "modulo 10" / "divide by 10" with "modulo 2" / "divide by 2" in your code - at least for unsigned integers. For signed integers, it *should also work that way™* but you may get negative values for the modulo (and of course for the division by 2, since the dividend is non-positive and the divisor is positive).

So to make this work without thinking about whether a number is signed or not, just grab one single bit after the other and right-sift the input until it is 0, while decrementing your arrays index, i.e. filling it "top-down" (since MSB0 first / left).

```
byte binaryArray[16];

binary ( int number ) 
{

   int index; 
   index = 15;

   for ( ; number != 0; ) 
   {
       binaryArray[index--] = number & 0x01;
       number = number >> 1;
   }
}
```

Side note: runtime (assuming one instruction as single effort) is the same as "modulo/divide by 2", since right-shifting by one equals dividing by 2. Actually, it is even a bit better, since binary-and (&) is "cheaper" than modulo (%).

But keep track of bit-ordering and endianness for this kind of conversions.